# annotate "include" file for grep with comments?

Tags: shell, grep

I do a `grep` sort that includes certain strings. That is, give me the lines in a file that DO contain certain strings. As in

```
grep -fv include file  > out
```

That command looks in `file` and sends to `out` every line that matches what is in the file `include`. No problem with that. Works fine.

BUT

How do I put comments in my `include` file?

For example, I'd like to annotate that file with some (e.g. `#`) comments that explain what I'm including. So I'd like for `grep` to ignore any lines in the `include` file that start with `#`. How do I do that?

Comment: The `v` gives an error. Could you correct your post?

Answer (score 1):

With shells having process substitution like bash and zsh:

```
grep -f <(grep -v '^#' include) file > out
```

Comment: But, oh dear. I can't get the "exclude" part to work. That is,

Comment: What "exclude" part?